# Laravel - Secure Way to Use SQL ids in JS/Http

Tags: mysql, laravel, encryption, routes

I'm making a web app where users can create pages, edit them, and delete them. In developing the prototype, I have a user access a route such as:

localhost:8000/mypage/1

The "1" in the URL refers to the ID in the database, so that the controller can fetch the appropriate associated data and populate the page accordingly.

The obvious problem here is that a user can plug in any number to that URL and edit someone else's page.

One obvious fix would be to add logic that checks whether or not page '1' belongs to the Auth::user(). But this would be an if statement that I have to add to every controller that carries out such function.

When I think about other sites, they never have ID's in the URL, or if they do, they look 'encrypted' in some form. What is the best practice for changing an ID into some uninterpretable string that I frequently see done on other websites?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "One obvious fix would be to add logic that checks whether or not page '1' belongs to the Auth::user(). But this would be an if statement that I have to add to every controller that carries out such function." Might help? https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes

Comment: Yes, I have this implemented already, but I don't believe this stops one authenticated user from accessing another authenticated users database info.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Comment: Hiding the ID is fine but it's not the solution for protecting resources from unauthorized requests.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use a middleware that check if the route can be acceded by the user? then you can call it with 
`$this->middleware('middlewareName');`
in the controller that you need it or even in the web.php if you want a whole set of routes protected